# Browser autofill not working with material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, autofill

I am trying to have browser autofill in one of my material dialog form. But I am facing issue with it. Tried several ways to show autofill but it's not visible.

Below is the code for html inside my dialog

```
<div id="manageFTPUsersAddEditModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <h4>Manage FTP User</h4>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div *ngIf="showMessage" class="{{messageClass}}">
        {{message}}
        <a href="#" class="close-button" (click)="hideMessage($event)">&times;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<form name="ftpUsersAddEditForm" #ftpUsersAddEditForm="ngForm" autocomplete="on">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <label class="middle">Friendly Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            <input id="ftpUserFriendlyName" name="friendlyName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.Ftpuserfriendlyname!.friendlyname" 
                autocomplete
            />
            <!-- <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="friendlyName"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.Ftpuserfriendlyname!.friendlyname" autocomplete="true"/> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <label class="middle">User Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            <input type="text" id="ftpUserName" name="username"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.username" [required]="required" autocomplete="username"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <label class="middle">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            <input type="text" id="ftpUsertxtPassword" name="password"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.password" [required]="Passwordrequired"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <label class="middle">Home Directory</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-1 columns">
            <label class="prefix middle">/data/</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-7 columns">
            <input type="text" id="ftpUsertxtHomedir" name="homeDirectory"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.homedirectory" autocomplete="homeDirectory"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="button" (click)="saveUser($event)">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="button secondary" (click)="closeManageUserModal($event)">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
<button class="close-button" (click)="closeManageUserModal($event)" type="button">
    <span><i class="ico-times"></i></span>
</button>
```

Kindly help me out in understanding what I am doing wrong or how I can initialize autofill in dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a autocomplete name the browser will recognize, only then autocomplete will work!

first go to Chrome -> settings -> autofill and more -> addresses -> then add an address

After adding address, give familiar names for autocomplete like `autocomplete="name"` and `autocomplete="username"`

After that its working for me in Chrome!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/knxdv5)